# Clear file name when enter directory name and enter

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser

I'm working on opening a file using `JFileChooser` Here is my code

```
JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
fileChooser.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);
FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("FF Files", "ff");
fileChooser.addChoosableFileFilter(filter);
int result = fileChooser.showDialog(null, "PP");
```

on a button click event these code will be running, very normal code I guess. When I click it, the JFileChooser dialog appears. If I enter a directory name in the `File Name` field (Ex. sam) and hit `Enter`, it enters to the directory, but the text field still shows the entered text i.e 'sam' I tried the same flow in notepad and in eclipse, in that phase, 'sam' getting cleared so that I can provide another directory name and hit enter.

Correct me if my code is wrong, If this problem is duplicate, I apology for wasted your time.

Comment: And your question would be?

Comment: @MadProgrammer How to make my code to behave like notepad's open dialog?

Comment: @Pasupathi it is not possible using Swing! Eclipse uses SWT and Notepad the native windows file chooser. Implementing your own file chooser is what you can do, or maybe you´ll find a library.

Comment: You could try using the AWT FileDialog(?)

Answer (score 1):

Notepad and Eclipse use a different implementation than `JFileChooser`. That´s why it might behave different and I don´t think you can do anything to make it work like you are expecting it (instead of using a custom library or making your own implementation).

Comment: I think you're correct about Notepad and Eclipse, I tried SOAP UI, similar behavior that I've stated can be reproduced.

Comment: @MadProgrammer Ya, that's what user714965 and I said.